# How to show bullets and numbering

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I have entered a text with bullets and numbering in CKeditor. I want to show it in the front end. How to save the ckeditor text with that styles that the user apply's.It only has ul li. No bullets when echoing it

Comment: Please show us what output you get and what output you expect. It is really unclear what exactly is happening.

Comment: Print it using {!! $content !!} brackets instead of {{ $content }}